# IP address obfuscation

Tags: dhcp

IP address obfuscation is a well known approach (for example, MLA
Kewley, Dorene, et al. "Dynamic approaches to thwart adversary intelligence gathering.") 
The approach suggested, is mainly used in networks with static IP addresses. I'm trying to understand why it will not work in a network with dynamic address translation. If I'll obfuscate the IP address in each packet Furthermore, I'll obfuscate the IP address and encrypt the payload of the packets from the DHCP server to the clients and vice versa.

Comment: This makes no sense at all. The IP address is needed to communicate with TCP/IP, i.e. an IP is needed before SSL/TLS can be done (since getting responses would not be possible).  Also, it is visible in all traffic between the endpoints (otherwise addressing and routing would not be possible) so hiding it from DHCP would not even help.  Note that the IP address in the local network is for home networks usually not the externally visible IP.

Comment: Why an IP address obfuscation/randomization doe's not make sense in an internal network?

Comment: You've asked about encryption. Obfuscation would not work either since all parties would have knowledge of the obfuscation mechanism to deobfuscate it - which makes it essentially no longer obfuscated. Randomization is not really possible since the IP range in the network is small. And like I said, the addresses are visible within the traffic anyway so why hide them in DHCP? The main problem might be that you try to have a technical solution for a problem you don't describe and which you might not even understand properly.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The problem I'm trying to solve is the spread of worms in the network, and trying to make an attacker "lose his grip" in a host. MTD approach trying to deal with that. One of the approaches is IP address obfuscation, and it's mainly tried on a network with static IP addresses. I'm trying to understand why I couldn't do it in a network with dynamic IP address.

Comment: I have no idea what your current approach really is. But to understand why encrypting the IP in DHCP will not help you would need to understand what DHCP is for and the basics of IP in a local network. Once you have this knowledge you will understand that the information provided by DHCP (i.e. association between IP and Mac) are visible in plain in the network even without DHCP.

Comment: @MissRobb: I've rejected the request to reopen the question after your edit since this is practically a completely different question you ask now and thus any existing comments and answers do not make any more sense. Please ask a new question instead.

Answer (score 2):

The DHCP protocol itself wasn't designed to have encryption and it's a very basic protocol of short `DISCOVER` -> `OFFER` &  `REQUEST` -> `ACKNOWLEDGE` packages. SSL/TLS especially wouldn't work here, as even negotiating such connection would need the DHCP to be used beforehand. Furthermore, it's not possible to simply add some encryption, as no-one would have an implementation that supports this, and it would be hard to modify these separately on every device.

There have been some attempts for *securing* ARP, to *authenticate* DHCP requests using 802.1x, and even to implement EAP in DHCP (EAPoDHCP), but those were all just drafts and there haven't been any work related to that lately. Interesting to read, though, e.g.:

- *Secure unicast address resolution protocol (S-UARP) by extending DHCP*
  by B. Issac;  L.A. Mohammed; DOI: [10.1109/ICON.2005.1635503](https://doi.org/10.1109/ICON.2005.1635503)
- *Secure ARP and Secure DHCP Protocols to Mitigate Security Attacks* [[PDF](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1410.4398.pdf)]
  by Biju Issac; International Journal of Network Security, Vol.8, No.2, PP.107-118, Mar. 2009

Also, all these proposals were mainly for *authenticating* the DHCP requests, not for *encypting* them. That's because no-one have really considered MAC and DHCP lease pairs as information that should be hidden from anyone who could capture those packets.

The reason those proposals were never widely accepted was the lack of demand: modern network security relies on creating confidentiality and integrity on a higher level. Even when there was a rogue DHCP server or unauthorized client, such technologies as DNSSEC and HTTPS prevents them from causing any real threat by providing lower layer independent *chains of trust*.